# Continuous NMR Coil arrangement and signal generation

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

So I am trying to understand how a signal is being produced in CW NMR and I cam across this online

[image]

An it talks about how the in CW the spectrum depends only the current being induced in the x-y plane. But what I dont understand is how the current in the CW b) is being generated if it is not precessing around the x-y axis like the pulse, method in d).

Link provied below.

https://wiley-vch.e-bookshelf.de/products/reading-epub/product-id/815770/title/NMR%2BSpectroscopy.html

Comment: Why do you think the nuclei are not precessing in the CW mode? They are being excited with a weak RF field, and will precess. There will only be a strong signal when the excitation is at the resonant frequency. So the amplitude of the response signal (transverse magnetization) depends on whether you are at (close to) resonance.